# Can I Set Google Analytics to Ignore Certain Sources or Locations?

Tags: google-analytics

Basically, I'd like my Google Analytics results to ignore me!

Thanks, as always.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add filters to exclude certain IPs from the stats. Here's an [article](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55481) on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude IP ranges from google analytics using regular expressions.  This is documented here:

http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55481

If you need help creating the appropriate regular expressions, google has a tool here:

http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55572